Apache VirtualHost Configuration - Unexpected Authentication Prompt Outside Internal Network
Here is the configuration:
I'm having an issue with my Apache VirtualHost configuration. I've set up pwauth for authentication and restricted access to a specific IP range (10.0.0.0/16) to make the server reachable only via the local IP. However, despite this configuration, I'm still able to access the site via its public URL and am prompted for user/password authentication, which is not the intended behavior. Instead, I want to see a 403 Forbidden message when accessing the site from outside the internal network.
When I remove the options AddExternalAuth  and SetExternalAuthMethod the desired outcome is only reached partially since im then able to recieve the 403 message from outside the internal network.
Here is a snippet of the configuration:
`
<VirtualHost 10.0.0.4:443>
ServerName 
AddExternalAuth pwauth /usr/sbin/pwauth
SetExternalAuthMethod pwauth pipe
DocumentRoot <Document-root>
<Directory <Documentroot>>
    AllowOverride None
    Options +FollowSymLinks

    # Default deny all access
    Require all denied

    # Allow only specific subnet
    <RequireAny>
        Require ip 10.0.0.0/16
    </RequireAny>

    # Authentication settings
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Admin"
    AuthBasicProvider external
    AuthExternal pwauth
    Require user <user list>
</Directory>

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/javascript

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile <cert path>
SSLCertificateKeyFile <cert path>

LogLevel warn
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

`
Thank you in advance
I already tried all the fixes i could find but to no avail, so therefore im asking here.
